# JMeter _jexl3 function with multiple conditions

Tags: jmeter, jexl

I'm a newbie in `Jmeter 4.0`.

I want a single IF controller in my Thread group executing True or False relation using Boolean ie; 0 and 1.

Currently i'm using two IF controllers with the expressions `${__jexl3(${VAR}==1)}` and `${__jexl3(${VAR}==0)}` and a single User Defined Variable with value Count==0.

The results are correct but I want it in a single IF controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vars.get` instead of `${}` syntax and use `||` for concatenating or conditions:

```
${__jexl3(vars.get("VAR")=="1" || vars.get("VAR")=="0")}
```

Comment: Why `vars.get`?

Comment: @FrankRobertAnderson this is the way to access JMeter variable inside a script

Comment: I mean, why use vars.get instead of `${}`? Are you saying `${}` doesn't work in scripts or is it inside of `__jexl3()`?